# How to autoscroll to next month in JTCalender with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, jtcalendar

I am showing events on the calendar as marked dates. So calendar shows January month by default. Now even if there is no even on January & event starts from march then still this month is shown as the first month & when i scroll to march then their dates are highlighted.

When i scroll to next month or previous below functions are called.

```
func calendarDidLoadNextPage(_ calendar: JTCalendarManager!) {

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
    print("load next date \(calendar.date())")
    label_month.text = formatter.string(from: calendar.date()).uppercased()
    filterDate(cal_date: calendar.date())
}

func calendarDidLoadPreviousPage(_ calendar: JTCalendarManager!) {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
    print("loading previous date is \(self.dateFormatter().string(from: calendar.date()))")
    label_month.text = formatter.string(from: calendar.date()).uppercased()
    filterDate(cal_date: calendar.date())
}
```

Please suggest, how can i autoscroll to that particular month?

Comment: Show the `filterDate` function

Comment: try reload your calendar view and check

Comment: calendarView.scrollToDate(NSDate(), triggerScrollToDateDelegate: false, animateScroll: false) {
                let currentDate = self.calendarView.currentCalendarDateSegment()
                self.setupViewsOfCalendar(currentDate.dateRange.start, endDate: currentDate.dateRange.end)
      }

Comment: You can set the current date for showing. For the current date you can set it as march month date.

Answer (score 0):

```
 func previse() {
    let date = calendarManager?.date()
    let nextDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: date!)
    calendarManager?.setDate(nextDate)
}
```

Comment: func next() {
        let date = calendarManager?.date()
        let nextDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: date!)
        calendarManager?.setDate(nextDate)
    }